# While Controller not working properly

Tags: while-loop, controller, jmeter

I am using JMeter for load testing. I am using `While Controller` to give a condition. The condition is:

```
${__javaScript("${__property(startingDocs)}" != "${__property(presentDocs)}" || "${__property(presentDocs)}" > 0,)}
```

Using this condition, the thread is running infinite time. But when I remove the statement after `OR`, it works fine i.e.

```
${__javaScript("${__property(startingDocs)}" != "${__property(presentDocs)}")}
```

How can I add the condition after using `OR`?

Answer (score 0):

In the condition after '||' you are trying to compare a string with a number 0. If 'presentDocs'is a number you should try using "parseInt()" and then compare it with "0"